# Pug JS: How to keep the entered values in input fields instead of clearing the form after validation

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, pug

I'm using NodeJS Express with Pug template and trying to keep the entered value of the input fields after submitted and failed invalidations. It seems to work in pure HTML but not with pug. I know something wrong with the syntax but I could not find a similar case on google. Please help.

Works:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" value="<%= typeof name != 'undefined'? name: '' %>
```

Does not work:

```
input#name.form-control(type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" value="<%= typeof name != 'undefined'? name: '' %>")
```

Comment: Your first code snippet doesn't validate, there's no closing `>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by way below:

- In pug file:

  `input(type="text", name="q", value= q)`
- In js file:

  ```
  app.get('/users/search', (req, res) => {
      var q = req.query.q;
      // something
      res.render('users/index', {
          q: q
      });
  })
  ```

  Hope it useful